# Mysql query with order by use index but still gives “using where”

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan, explain

I'm encountering a problem with the following query:

```
select * 
from testtable 
where user_id = 1 and color = 1 and size = 1 
order by created_at desc, id desc;
```

I was using two index

- `index1 (user_id, color, size)`
- `index2 (created_at, id)`

But i got "using where, using filesort" in the explain result

Then i changed the index to use all the five columns

- `index1 (user_id ... id)`

And the "using filesort" gone, but i still get "using where"

What further steps should i take in order to completely use the indexes for this query?

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Unless you specifically intend to fetch or examine **all** rows from the table, you may have something wrong in your query if the Extra value is not **Using where**

[From the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html)

So in other word this is absolutely normal and OK.

Comment: You should include an attribution link for the quoted material.

Answer (score 0):

The first index is used for the `where`.  If you also want to use the index for sorting, then you need an index on `(user_id, color, size, created_at, id)`.

Comment: In the explanation i corrected it to include all the columns like in your example but i still get "using where"